# Emacs elisp debugger: How do i make the debugger jump to source when i press s?

Tags: debugging, symbols, tags, debug

The builtin elisp debugger (i.e. the regular one, `debug`, *not* edebug) has a default binding of `s` to command `backtrace-goto-source`.

When I try to use it, it says: `Source code location not known`

You can see what I mean by doing this:

1. Set contents of `/tmp/blah.el` to be:

```lisp
(defun abc ()
  (error "hello"))
```

2. Run the command `emacs -Q --eval '(progn (setq debug-on-error t) (load-file "/tmp/blah.el") (abc))'`
3. Highlight fourth line in buffer, the one that reads   `abc()`
4. Press `s` key, the error says `Source code location not known`

The docs for `backtrace-goto-source` say:

`If its location is known, jump to the source code for the frame at point`

I checked the builtin info documentation for section *18.1 The Lisp Debugger*, but i couldn't really find a setting for what i want. How do I make a symbol's location known to the debugger so it jumps to the source location when I press s?

Interesting note: the behavior of pressing mouse-1 is completely different from pressing s, and sometimes navigates to bundled source location gzs for me, but also sometimes opens an "Open File" dialog (GUI).

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Please provide a recipe to repro what you describe. Which debugger? etc.

Comment: @drew Ok i added a recipe.

Comment: Please don't pose multiple questions in a single post, or your post risks being closed. Some of the questions you pose here are related, so OK as background to your problem. But a question like your last one belongs as a separate post. Thx.

Comment: @Drew I didn't mean it as multiple questions. I meant it all as one question (how to get the debugger to find symbols) where i preferred the answer to work across multiple projects at once. I have updated the question, nonetheless, to make it easier for people trying to home in on what i'm actually asking here. Is it ok now?

Comment: Looks good. Thanks.

Comment: Does `M-.` (bound to `xref-find-definitions`) work? Also `RET` or `<mouse-1>`?

Comment: Missed your "interesting note" before: so pressing `<mouse-1>` does not jump to the definition of `abc` in your example? I ran your example and I can get to the `abc` defun using any of the three methods in my comment (but `s` indeed does not work - I think because `backtrace-goto-source-functions` is nil).  I think this is worth submitting as a bug with `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s` is bound to a new function that was recently added, and indeed it appears to be non–functional. I took a look at the source code, and it does attempt to pull file and line number from the stack frame, but none of the stack frames have any file and line number information :)

It then tries to run hook functions, but the list of hook functions is empty. Those hooks are the ones that are supposed to open the correct source file.

It would be helpful if you could open a bug report about this (use `M-x report-emacs-bug`). It may be that some part of the implementation was left out, or that it was never finished. Probably the best fix is to simply remove the key binding until the problem is fixed.

In the mean time, hitting enter (or left clicking) on any line in the stack trace will take you to the definition of the named function, if it can find it. On most code this will work just fine, but it isn’t very helpful in some situations, such as when someone has called `eval`. In those cases you can jump to the definition of `eval` or to any of the functions that the evaluated code calls, but there’s no way to jump to the code it is evaluating.